# Attunity Terada - Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, teradata, attunity

Can anybody tell me if it is possible using Attunity for Teradata database and a Sql Server 2008 R2 database to have the "false load" loaded in a database and the logs in a different database?

Thank you so much, 
Bogdan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else wants to know, YES it is possible to have a different dabase for error tables when using attunity connector.
If one uses SSIS package in which attunity connector is used, all you have to do is to go in properties for that dataflow task object, to section "[teradata destination].[ErrorTableName]" and there you can write the name for desired database.table_name.